# Circuit with a tip120 works with a Led but, don't with a vibrator motor

Tags: arduino-nano, power

I have 2 Arduino Nano's. One with RF transmitter and the other with an RF receiver of 433 MHz and both have two 3v vibration motors. I want one Arduino to send a string to the other Arduino to let him know which vibrator he needs to vibrate. The connection works, when the Arduino with the transmitter sends a message, the other Arduino gets the message and sets pin 2 (the pin for the vibrator via a tip120) HIGH. But the vibrator does not vibrate. When I change the vibrator with a led it works, the led goes on and off. So why does the led work but the vibrator motor not?

I use the VirtualWire library for the RF modules.

Here is the code and I also provided a summary:

Summary: This is the receiver Arduino code. `message_received` is the string variable where the message is stored and in the loop, that message is to check what it contains. And then the led goes off and on.

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

byte message[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN]; // a buffer to store the incoming messages
byte messageLength = 255; // the size of the message

String message_received;

String message_go_on = "GO_ON";
String message_go_off = "GO_OF";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
  vw_rx_start(); // Start the receiver
  Serial.println("RECEIVER MONITOR");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (vw_get_message(message, &messageLength)){ // Non-blocking
    Serial.print("Incoming message: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++){
      Serial.write(message[i]);
      message_received += (char)message[i];
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
  if(message_received == message_go_on){
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  }
  if(message_received == message_go_off){
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  }
  message_received = "";
}
```

---

Summary: This is the code of the transmitter. I have 2 messages that I want to send every 200 milliseconds. The send method is for the transmitter and it needs a char array so I change the string to a char[] with a toCharArray() method.

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

String message_go_on = "GO_ON";
String message_go_off = "GO_OF";

char buf1[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
char buf2[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec

  message_go_on.toCharArray(buf1,VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN);
  message_go_off.toCharArray(buf2,VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN);
  Serial.println("TRNASMITTER MONITOR");
}

void loop() {
  send(buf1);
  delay(200);
  send(buf2);
  delay(200);
}

void send (char *message)
{
  vw_send((uint8_t *)message, strlen(message));
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
}
```

The circuit of the receiver Arduino:
[image: The circuit of the receiver Arduino]

I think the vibrator might be undersupplied but why would the led work?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where is the vibrator? off screen at the bottom of the picture?

Comment: why did you post all that code? ... you said that it works with an LED, so a simple LED blink code should be used to troubleshoot the motor problem

Answer (score 3):

The TIP120 is possibly the worst transistor you could choose for this job. It is a Darlington Pair transistor, and those have a (relatively) massive forward drop of between 2 and 4 volts. It works with the LED because an LED needs a tiny amount of current to operate compared to the motor and has a fixed forward voltage of its own. The motor doesn't, and is being starved of power by that huge voltage drop (it's getting maybe half the voltage it should be getting).

Throw away that TIP120 and replace it with a decent N-channel MOSFET - one with a "threshold voltage" (V<sub>GS</sub>) of 2.5V or less ideally.

Comment: Also note that to drive an inductive load like a motor you'll need a [**flyback diode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) to protect the transistor from back EMF.

Comment: @DuncanC Like the one you can see on the breaboard image?

Comment: I'm not going to try to trace out a picture of a breadboard. Now that you mention it I do see a diode in the breadboard, but it's worth calling out anyway because others who are not aware of the requirement read this tread